# whether to use Flask-Navigation

Tags: python, flask, flask-nav

I've implemented navigation in a small flask powered website like this and it seems to do the job:

```
<!-- Navigation (Stays on Top) -->
<div class="w3-top w3-bar w3-black">
<a href="page1" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
<a href="page2" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Page 2</a>
<a href="Page3" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Page 3</a>
</div>
```

Inside views.py for Page 2 is :

```
@imprint.route("/page2")
def page2_view():
    return render_template("page2.html")
```

and homologous for the other pages.

Is there any security risk or other issue with this, why would one instead use the package -
https://flask-navigation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I don't see how there would be any security risks, but you might have some lag by it rendering the template on each request.

Comment: I just read [here](https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-jinja-templates/) _Even though sites seemed to have common elements between pages (such as navigation), the reality was a nightmare of hardcoding these elements by hand on every individual page of a site. Changing a navigation link meant manually making the same change across hundreds of pages._ So a warning to anyone reading this, it may not be a security issue but probably don't do this if you have a site with lots and lots of pages.

Comment: It's good to know about this lag in rendering the template on each request. I think in my case, each of the small number of pages has a different form, divs etc so probably have to render with each request anyhow. But if I end up with several pages one day, where they all have similar form, but just different content populated by Flask and Jinja, will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your approach. As [Froggo has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642987/whether-to-use-flask-navigation#comment131778600_74642987), this might cause a small amount of lag as you are rendering the template for each request, but other than that, it should be fine.

As for the [Flask-Navigation package](https://github.com/tonyseek/flask-navigation), one of the reasons why people are inclined to use it as it provides a level of convenience for making navigation bars. But looking more closely at the repository, it seems that development has been halted ([the last recorded commit was around 7 years ago at the time of writing](https://github.com/tonyseek/flask-navigation/commits/develop)).

If you do want to use a dedicated navigation package, then [Flask-Nav](https://github.com/mbr/flask-nav) seems to be a good contender, but just as the Flask-Navigation package, this package is also not actively maintained. However, this package is being actively used (according to GitHub), and the [community has a workaround to get this package to work with the latest version of Python (3.10.x)](https://github.com/mbr/flask-nav/pull/27).

I hope this research helps you.